# What means > in Cypress

Tags: css-selectors, cypress, automation-testing, relative-locators

```js
cy.get('.pass-input-placeholder > .input-wrapper > .error-msg > .msg-body > span')
  .should('contain', 'Invalid password');
```

Why are the classes separated with ">"? Does it apply only for classes?

Answer (score 2):

It means select "the immediate child". It applies for classes, tags, ids, attributes, anything.

So `.pass-input-placeholder > .input-wrapper` would find this

```html
<div class="pass-input-placeholder">
  <div class="input-wrapper">
```

but not this

```html
<div class="pass-input-placeholder">
  <div>
    <div class="input-wrapper">
```

But without `>` the second HTML will be found as well.

```js
cy.get('.pass-input-placeholder .input-wrapper')  // finds any descendent
```